# Structure of "that living processes leave"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

What are the structure and meaning of the bolded expression?

> Detritus refers to all the dead organic debris **that living processes
>   leave**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here "that living processes leave" is a relative clause that describes "the dead organic debris".

Living processes, i.e. processes related to life and biology, leave some dead materials and debris which is called Detritus.